# google calendar discontinuing support for json rpc and api-java-client

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-calendar-api

We use Google APIs Calendar v3 and Google said that they'll  discontinuing support for json rpc [Discontinuing support for JSON-RPC and Global HTTP Batch Endpoints](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html).

I cant find if they plan a v4 version compliant or if the current version is compliant. Documentation don't reference about it. [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java)

Any information about that?

Comment: Are you actually using the batching endpoint currently?

Comment: Yes we are using BatchRequest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not just Calendar that is effected its all Google APIs discovery APIs that are effected.  The batching endpoint

```
POST /batch HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_foobarbaz
Content-Length: total_content_length
```

Will be discontinued around March 25, 2019.  That being said i am skeptical that the client libraries have all been updated to remove it already.  I am a contributor on two of them and haven't heard anything yet about removing the the batching ability from the libraries.

> Google API Client Libraries have been regenerated to no longer make
>   requests to the global HTTP batch endpoint. Clients using these
>   libraries must upgrade to the latest version. Clients not using the
>   Google API Client Libraries and/or making custom calls to the JSON-RPC
>   endpoint or HTTP batch endpoint will need to make the changes outlined
>   below.

The global batching endpoint is

> www.googleapis.com/batch

the new one is

> www.googleapis.com/batch/<api>/<version>

I think the choice of words incorrect here and it they will be regenerated if needed.  The change should not effect users with one exception.  That being heterogeneous batch requests a single batch request containing more then one API within the call wont work due to the fact that the end point is API specific.

Now for the bad news to my knowledge there is nothing that is going to be replacing it. You will not be able to make heterogeneous batch requests. The Google apis java client library appears to use the old endpoint [BatchRequest.java](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/blob/4fc8c099d9db5646770868cc1bc9a33c9225b3c7/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/batch/BatchRequest.java#L100)  so if you are using heterogeneous batching your going to have to change your code by the time they update the library to support the new API specific endpoint.

**Update**

After a lot of back and forth with Google over the last 24 hours I have gotten some clarification on that post.

1. Batching will still work with the client libries
2. Most of the client libraries appear to already use this endpoint so there should be no change.
3. You will only be able to call one API within a batch request.  Example you cant call drive and calendar API in the same batch request.  You will have to make two batch requests one for drive and one for calendar.

There may be some edits coming to that post to clear up the language a little to be more clear.

I have updated my answer to reflect the clarifications from Google

Comment: So to replace batching, we need to rework our code to do multiple requests with standard java api ?

Comment: The client libraries have not been ALL regenerated (at least not the PHP one, I have just checked it, and last update of the Batch class is november 2017) ! Anyway, there's a 1 year delay before shutdown, I guess client libraries will be updated soon.

Comment: .net hasn't been updated eather but we are planning to.   I am trying to get it delayed to give developers time.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque you will only have to make multiple requests if your mixing different apis in different calls check the *heterogeneous batch request example* in the document.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some Information i got from Google over the last 12 hours.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have changed https://www.googleapis.com/batch to https://www.googleapis.com/batch/calendar/v3 it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

It is not removing batching entirely.

Per the [blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html) they are removing heterogeneous batching - accessing the same API with requests that lead to other APIs. They are also consolidating homogeneous batching (batching to the same API and leading to a singular API) to "API specific batch endpoints".

From my understanding of the blog, if you are batching several different requests, ie. a Foo request and a Bar request into a Foo API call, you will have to adjust your code to use one batch for one and one batch for the other. If you are already doing that, it is unclear whether or not you will have to change your code, perhaps newly released libraries will have a new way to handle these requests.

Comment: It's an interesting answer, I'll check my code. If I do homogenous batch requests, maybe I'll wait and see.